# Is there a way to remove these thin line frame around IrfanView?

Tags: frame, irfanview

They're more noticeable when in maximize windows:

> [image].

Comment: How do I set the border to 0 or use alternative style? I'm using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

These borders are part of the default Windows 7 windows appearance. Eithe set your border to 0 pixels width or use an alternative style.

Both may require hacks, and will not be limited to just IrfanView

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 4.60 (Release date: 2022-03-18) there is a shortcut that will permit "thin" borders, in a way similar to the original request:

New hotkey: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>: Show thin or normal border (current session only)